# Is "dc=nomain" a in LDAP ACLs?

Tags: ldap, authentication, domain-controller, openldap, access-control-list

I'm trying to set up my first LDAP server. I can't get clients to authenticate using it even though everything seems to be working. i suspect the ACLs might be the problem since i can't see the ACLs using the command given by the official ubuntu guide:

```
ldapsearch -xLLL -b cn=config -D cn=admin,cn=config -W olcDatabase=hdb olcAccess
```

i can see them using this command though:

```
sudo ldapsearch -Q -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config '(olcDatabase={1}hdb)' olcAccess
```

The second command shows that the first entry in the ACL uses `dc=nodomain` :

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by dn="cn=admin,dc=nodomain" write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=nodomain" write by * read
```

Is this the problem? how do i fix it? i can't find a way to edit the ACLs without completely changing the installation using `dpkg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a test system without a real hostname (like `ldap.example.org`) and name it just `ldap`, the default configuration of OpenLDAP on Debian(?)/Ubuntu (which I guess you use) will assume an LDAP tree with the name `dc=nodomain` and create appropriate ACL rules.

Really, your best approach is to set a complete FQDN and let `dpkg --reconfigure slapd` do it's work. It will destroy everything, but you end up with a valid LDAP tree and an admin user like `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org`.